# Need to calculate next milestone in the sequence

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset something like this

[image]

I want to calculate the next clinical milestone for the ID as per the sequence number.
E.g. for 665 the next clinical milestone as per the sequence should be DBF as it doesn't have any date present in the actual column  ( we need to ignore the intermediate values like FPA and FCI where data isn't present for column actual as data is really dirty and dates can be smaller compared to last one in sequence.)

There is another case where all data in the actual column for an ID is null then, in that case first non-null planned column value for that clinical milestone should be the next one.

e.g. in ID 666 CPC should be the next clinical milestone.

Thought using LAG function as well for this using max of actual for an ID but not sure how will it work when two rows have same actual date.

Comment: Just to clarify, could there be `NULL` values in `planned` in the middle of the sequence?  For example, for `id=665`, could row 10 have `planned=NULL`?  And if it did, would row 11 be the next milestone?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/53341/matbailie  Yes it can have null present in it. In that particular instance, the next milestone should be row 11.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/53341/matbailie I already removed the intermediate ones where both planned actual is null

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/53341/matbailie can you suggest some good resource on spark SQL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MAX() OVER ()` with a `CASE` expression to work out the current sequence value for each `id`, then filter based on that.

```
WITH
  resequenced AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY sequence)  AS new_sequence
  FROM
    yourTable
  WHERE
       actual  IS NOT NULL
    OR planned IS NOT NULL
),
  summarised AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    MAX(CASE WHEN actual IS NOT NULL THEN new_sequence ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY id)  AS last_sequence
  FROM
    resequenced
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  summarised
WHERE
  new_sequence = last_sequence + 1
```

***EDIT***: Adapted to deal with gaps in Both the `actual` and `planned` columns.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/53341/matbailie this condition will fail when planned column and actual column both have null values as I mentioned in the second case first non null planned date column value should be considered for the next clinical milestone and same for the first case as well.

Comment: @sharma_re - Then please edit your example data to actually show that scenario.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/53341/matbailie Thanks for the solution. Edited the question too